# How to know the path of a yum repository?

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

when I run the yum repolist , I get the follwoing repositories names

```
  yum repolist

  Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
  This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
  repo id                                                           repo  name                                                                                           status
  rhel-x86_64-server-5                                              Red Hat      Enterprise Linux (v. 5 for 64-bit x86_64)                                                  10817
  info                                                              Red Hat     Enterprise Linux target-5 - x86_64                                                            6988
  repolist: 24235
```

regarding the **info** repository , this repo defined in the file - ghhds.repo

```
[info]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
baseurl=http://ghhds/mnt/rtv/yum/rel/base/info
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

what is very strange is that I not see the repo - r**hel-x86_64-server-5** in the files under **/etc/yum.repos.d**

so from where I get this respiratory?  , if this is local repository how to know the PATH or repository location ?

or maybe this repository is external red-hat repository  ?